# Custom Test Orchestrator or callback for start/finish

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, android-junit, androidjunitrunner

I'm using the `Android Test Orchestrator` to run my UI tests and i need to generate a report of the results when all the tests are finished.
I need to have a callback for when the orchestrator starts running the tests and when it finishes running all of them in a way that i can generate and save my report.

Given that a new instance of the `AndroidJUnitRunner` is created for every tests, i can't take advantage of `onStart()` and `finish()` to do that.

I was looking for a way to maybe provide a custom orchestrator so i can use the internal methods..